# map must alteast have 2 argument

Tags: python

Good day to all programmers I am having a bit of a struggle trying to run my code it says my map needs at least two arguments I tried closing it all in brackets but the same run time error occurs.

```py
import numpy as np

with open( 'input.txt' ) as fin:
   text = fin.read()
   output = open( 'output.txt', 'w')
    
for line in text:
   print(line)
   parts = line.split(':')
   op = parts[0].strip()   # remove possible spaces
   nums = list(map(parts[0].strip().split(',')))
      
   print (output,'The', op, 'of', nums, 'is',)
   if op == 'Avg':
      print (output,np.mean(nums))
   elif op == 'Min':
      print (output,min(nums))
   elif op == 'Max':
      print (output,max(nums))
   else:
      print (output,'wrong operation',op)
```

Thanks, much appreciated

Comment: I think you probably meant `list(map(int, parts[0].strip().split(',')))`

Comment: The code does not run this way, because the indentation is broken. Would you please [edit] the question and fix the indentation?

Comment: Your indentation kills the program.  A majority of the posted code has nothing to do with your question.  Your output file isn't necessary, and the input file doesn't exist on our machines.  Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Most of all, the error message is quite correct.  Please consult the `map` documentation.  Where do you have trouble understanding how it works?  You need a function to apply and an iterable to which you apply it.  You supplied only the second.

Answer (score 0):

You should include iterable element which is to be mapped. Syntax should be like map(fun, iter).

fun : It is a function to which map passes each element of given iterable.
iter : It is a iterable which is to be mapped.